# Complex number question?

Tags: complex-numbers

Are there only finitely many complex numbers $z$ such that $z^{634}=1$?

I think there are only finitely many; is that not so?

Comment: There are exactly $634$ unique complex solutions, two of which ($\pm 1$) are purely real.

Comment: If $(re^{i\theta})^{634}=1$, then $r=1$ and $\theta=\dfrac{2\pi n}{634}$

Comment: Check out de Moivre's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are only finitely many $634^{th}$ complex roots of unity.

This is easily seen with polar notation.  Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $z^{634}=1$.

Then $r=1$ and $\theta=\dfrac{2\pi n}{634}$.

There are only finitely many values of $n$ (viz., $634$) such that $0\le\dfrac{2\pi n}{634}<2\pi$.

Comment: There are, however, countably infinite values of $\theta$ such that $e^{i\theta}=1$ without the restriction $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$

Comment: @Graviton:  you are correct, but they don't correspond to infinitely many complex numbers