# Complex number $|z|$=1

Tags: complex-numbers

Are there only finitely many complex numbers $z$ with $|z|=1$?

I think there are infinitely many such numbers.

Comment: $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Contrast [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923093/complex-number-question)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are infinitely many complex numbers $z$ with $|z|=1$, including $e^{2 \pi i/n}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to focus on the roots of unity in this case? After all, it works for $e^{i \theta}$ for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ in general.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer:  not particularly, though the ones I focused on did answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, all complex numbers on the circle $S^1$: namely all numbers of the form $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... sure.  Here's a graph of them:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

$$|z|=1$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$$
$${x^2+y^2}=1.$$